# Python function overloading recommended approach

Tags: python, function, oop, type-hinting, constructor-overloading

Assume a function that takes an object as parameter. There could be various ways to express the parameter object creation, some of which expressive, and likely easier to be used.

To give a simple example, we have a function which takes `DateTime`. We also want to accept string representations of DateTime, if possible (for example `'20220606'`).

```py
# version 1, strict. must send a DateTime  
def UsefulFunc(startdate: DateTime) -> None:
    pass

# version 2, allow more types, but loose on type hints
def UsefulFunc(startdate: (DateTime, str)) -> None:
    # check if type is str, convert to DateTime if yes
    pass

# version 3, multiple signatures to accept and call the base function 
def UsefulFuncString(startdatestr: str) -> None:
    # convert startdatestr to DateTime
    UsefulFunc(startdate)

# … …
```

What approach is recommended in Python (I come from C# background)? If there's no clear indication/ or decision is based on situation, what are the considerations?

Comment: Are you asking how to *implement* the function or how to write type hints for it, accepting all 3 versions? Or are you asking which of the 3 versions is best?

Comment: Have you looked at `typing.overload`? (Though I would lean towards multiple distinct functions rather than a single function that can accept multiple types.)

Comment: In any case, I think version 2 needs to use `DateTime | str` or `Union[DateTime, str]` rather than `(DateTime, str)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, and taking inspirations from the @Copperfield answer, I found an elegant solution to the problem.

Let's first rephrase the problem - we have a function that takes an object. We want to provide some overloads, which will do the validations/ conversions etc. and call the base function which accepts object. We also need to reject any call not following any function signature which are not implemented.

The library that I found very useful was [multipledispatch](https://pypi.org/project/multipledispatch/). An easy example:

```py
from multipledispatch import dispatch

@dispatch(int, int)
def add_nums(num1: int, num2: int) -> int:
  return num1 + num2

@dispatch(str, str)
def add_nums(num1: str, num2: str) -> int:
  # do some useful validations/ object transformations
  # implement any intermediate logic before calling the base func
  # this enables base function do it's intended feature rather than    
  # implementing overloads 
  return add_nums(int(num1), int(num2))
```

if we call `add_nums(40, 15)`, we get `55` as the `(int, int)` version get called. `add_nums('10', '15')` get us `25` as expected as `(str, str)` version get called.

It becomes very interesting when we call `add_nuns(10, 10.0)` as this will fail saying `NotImplementedError: Could not find signature for add_nums: <int, float>`. Essentially any call not in `(int, int)` or `(str, str)` format, fail with `NotImplementedError` exception.

This is by far the closest behaviour of function overloading, when comparing with typed languages.

The only concern I have - this library was last updated on Aug 9, 2018.

Comment: Problems with library `multipledispatch`: 
1. Some type checkers raise errors. flake8 gave `redefinition of unused add_nums from line 4`
2. Code editors only show the last function signature.

Comment: Another library which is much more comprehensive and actively managed is [plum](https://github.com/wesselb/plum). Our implementation will look exactly the same as in the answer except there is no need to put the types in `@dispatch`. The code editor still cry about redefinition though.

Comment: another useful read [flake8 VS Code support lacking for multi-dispatch](https://github.com/wesselb/plum/issues/46#issuecomment-1152251857).

Answer (score 1):

if you want type hint your function, you can use [typing.Union](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Union)

```
from datetime import datetime
from typing import Union
def UsefulFunc(startdate:Union[str, datetime]) -> None
    ...
```

or in py3.10+

```
def UsefulFunc(startdate:str|datetime) -> None
    ...
```

but type hint are just decoration in python, if you want to do something base on those types you need to check inside your function and work accordingly

```
 def UsefulFunc(startdate:str|datetime) -> None
    if isinstance(startdate,str):
        ...
    elif isinstance(startdate,datetime): 
        ...
    else:
        raise ValueError("Invalid type")
```

There is also the [functools.singledispatch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.singledispatch) that help you do the above for you

```
from functools import singledispatch

@singledispatch
def UsefulFunc(startdate):
    ... #else case

@UsefulFunc.register
def _(startdate:datetime):
    ... #datetime case

@UsefulFunc.register
def _(startdate:str):
    ... #str case
```

Comment: `singledispatch` is useful/ clean way to implement, which I was not aware of. I believe this could give the closest implementation as in typed languages. On that merit, marking as answer. This answer and many comments assumed that I want to know how to use type hints. Which I was not. I was asking if those helper constructor Pytonic (or function callers must always pass `DateTime`, and take care of conversion). Also, in case of `singledispatch`, text editors show signature of `UsefulFunc` as `def _SingleDispatchCallable(*args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> _T`, not much useful.